# Compiling triangulation_2 demo on CGAL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cgal

Im just installed CGAL on Windows 8 for Visual Studio 2010 following this tutorial http://www.cgal.org/windows_installation.html#PrerequisitesforCompilingthe32-bitCGALLibraryusingMicrosoftVisualStudio2010. When im trying to compile a demo with CMake, it says:

```
The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 2010 -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Build type: Release
USING CXXFLAGS = ' /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -    D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /fp:strict     /fp:except- /wd4503 /bigobj /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG'
USING EXEFLAGS = ' /machine:X86  /INCREMENTAL:NO'
Targetting Visual Studio 10 2010
Target build enviroment supports auto-linking
Using VC10 compiler.
Generator uses intermediate configuration directory: $(Configuration)
Requested component: Qt4
Found OpenGL: opengl32  
Looking for Q_WS_X11
Looking for Q_WS_X11 - not found
Looking for Q_WS_WIN
Looking for Q_WS_WIN - found
Looking for Q_WS_QWS
Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
Looking for Q_WS_MAC
Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
Found Qt4: C:/Qt/4.8.6/bin/qmake.exe (found version "4.8.6") 
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
NOTICE: This demo requires CGAL and Qt4, and will not be compiled.
Configuring done
```

Comment: You are probably using cmake-3, which is not yet supported by CGAL.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the problem @MarcGlisse

Comment: @MarcGlisse Please promote your comment to an answer. I would like to mark the answer as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue typically occurs when you use version 3+ of cmake. That version is not supported by CGAL-4.4, support will appear in CGAL-4.5. In the mean time, please use an older version of cmake.